# Problem with the social-share-button gem for Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Wondering if anyone has experience with this [social-share-button gem for Rails](https://github.com/huacnlee/social-share-button)?

I have installed the gem ok and get the social share buttons to show, but upon clicking (dev environment) nothing happens.

I get the following error in the Chrome console every time I click:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: SocialShareButton is not defined at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick (VM7889 62:777) onclick @ VM7889 62:777
```

It looks like SocialShareButton is defined in the gem in the social-share-button.coffee file I can see on GitHub but don't know where to go from there.

Comment: did you run `rails generate social_share_button:install` ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was there was confusion around where to put the

```
#= require social-share-button
```

As I did not have a `app/assets/javascripts/application.coffee` file and so the `#=` did not work in my `application.js` file.

I changed this to `//= require social-share-button` in `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` and it threw a new error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined ...
```

I assumed this meant I needed jQuery (even though it looked like the gem had been updated to remove the need for jQuery based on their notes), so I installed that and voila! It works.